# Programmatically update variable values in .tfvars file?

Tags: terraform

Before I go ahead and create something I wanted to check does anyone know of a CLI or other tool to update the values within a .tfvars file?

Example vars file:

```
ecs_desired_capacity      = 1
ecs_asg_min_size          = 1
```

What I'd like:

```
./somecommand ./myvars.tfvars --set="ecs_asg_min_size=2,new_var=1"
```

Result edit file:

```
ecs_desired_capacity      = 1
ecs_asg_min_size          = 2
new_var = 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HCLQ](https://github.com/mattolenik/hclq) (command line tool for querying and manipulating HashiCorp HCL):

```
cat myvars.tfvars | hclq set 'ecs_asg_min_size' 2
```

you can add a new variable and then check its value or update it

```
echo "new_var = 1" >> myvars.tfvars
cat myvars.tfvars | hclq get 'new_var'
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
#!/bin/sh

# Example usage:
# ./update_tfvars.sh example.tfvars variable_name_here 123

set -e

tfvars_file=$1
var_name=$2
var_value=$3

sed -r -i -e "s/($var_name\s*=\s*).*/\1$var_value/" $tfvars_file
```

Doesn't add a new entry if it doesn't exist, which fits my needs.